# WIFI disappears until reboot

Tags: wi-fi, oneplus-7

Ok so I've encountered this on multiple devices across multiple networks so I'm 90% sure it's an issue with the core OS but it's been happening for over a year and hasn't been fixed at all.

About once a day my device will drop its wifi connection and when I open the wifi settings page it cannot scan/locate any nearby networks for me to join. It just kinda hangs saying that it's searching for nearby networks but it never shows me anything (even though I know there should be about a dozen nearby since I live in an apartment style building). Toggling wifi on/off does not help, nor does toggling airplane mode. The wifi settings page remains empty no matter what. The only solution I have been able to find is to do a full device reboot then everything works fine for another day or two.

I've encountered this on both the google pixel slate (worst purchase ever, returned it) and a OnePlus 7pro. The behaviour has been **identical** across both devices.

I've read some old articles saying to disable ipv6 support but I don't even have that option on the OnePlus phone (and honestly I wouldn't be happy if that was the solution).

I'm a senior software engineer at a major tech company and I can't figure this out and I can't get any legitimate help from the companies behind these devices. What can I even do?

I am open to troubleshooting suggestions or if someone can help me gather debug information to submit a more official report that would be great. Right now I have no way to get official support, the people at oneplus are just giving me the usual runaround of doing a factory reset etc without even examining the issue... and google has worse customer support than comcast.

Comment: If it happens with two devices from different manufacturer you may encounter a bug in the used Wifi subsystem which is AFAIK at large parts identical to whyt current Linux distributions use. Therefore it would be interesting if you also encounter this problem on a regular Linux-System (if it also happens there debugging will be easier and the [community] support of Linux distros is usually very good). May be someone has set-up a Wifi next to you that causes this error.

Comment: I use Linux on all my home laptops and they don't have an issue. Also annoyingly I have other android devices that don't have an issue. My guess is it could be a hardware choice in the devices that are having issues where the hardware is not playing nice with the OS